# The 'a' HTML tag calls window.location.assign behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, hyperlink

Kind of new to the web world, hence basic question here.

Let's say I have a very basic `a` tag in my HTML:

```
<a href="www.google.com">
  Click me
</a>
```

What does exactly happen when I click on the link? Will the browser just do a `window.location.assign`? Maybe a `window.location.replace`? Or something completely different?

I am trying to understand how hyperlinks work and I am quite lost here. Thank you for any help! :)

EDIT: Thanks to the first comment, now I know that those hare JS functions (not HTML things). So what is `a` doing behind the scenes? Not calling any function/method at all?

Comment: No, the browser will not call any of those JS functions when an <a> tag with href is clicked. You can test this by overriding the assign and replace functions in a document.

Comment: Actually I was running some tests were I expected window.location.assign to be called --no need to say the tests failed miserably. What function will be called instead? How does the DOM handle this?

Comment: The routine executing when a link is activated is within the browser implementation. You cannot hook into it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: A link will  navigate a browsing context to a resource, see [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#navigate), this has nothing to do with JS.

Comment: @marekful I just wanted to know what routine was executed when the link was activated. I thought it would be something general, not depending on the browser implementation. Since I am activating the link in NodeJS (not in the browser), no routine is called. Your previous comment actually solves my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML `<a>` tag *(with a specified `href=""`)* click event is **implemented by the browser** and does **not** call any JavaScript functions. That would only be unnecessary because every browser can handle the click and redirection events just fine themselves.
The reason is performance. Pointing events like clicking a link to JavaScript is not optimal when the browser is able to execute such tasks "in real-time".

Hope this clarifies this topic for you :)